# visual studio swprintf is making all my %s formatters want wchar_t * instead of char *

Tags: visual-studio, printf

Ive got a multi platform project that compiles great on mac, but on windows all my swprintf calls with a %s are looking for a wchar_t instead of the char * im passing it. Turns out M$ thought it would be funny to make %s stand for something other than char * in wide character functions... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx

Anyways I'm looking for a creative coding trick thats better than putting ifdef else ends around every wide string call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: VS 2015 CTP6 reverted the changes and Microsoft are yet again acting different to the standard.

---

[Visual Studio 14 CTP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/18/crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx) <strike>and later</strike> will always treat `%s` as a narrow string (`char*`) unless you define `_CRT_STDIO_LEGACY_WIDE_SPECIFIERS`. It also added the T length modifier extension which maps to what MS calls the "natural" width. For `sprintf` `%Ts` is `char*` and for `swprintf` `%Ts` is  `wchar_t*`.

---

In Visual Studio 13 and earlier `%s`/`%c` is mapped to the natural width of the function/format string and `%S`/`%C` is mapped to the opposite of the natural with:

```
printf("%c %C %s %S\n", 'a', L'B', "cd", L"EF");
wprintf(L"%c %C %s %S\n", L'a', 'B', L"cd", "EF");
```

You can also force a specific width by using a length modifier: `%ls`, `%lc`, `%ws` and `%wc` always mean `wchar_t` and `%hs` and `%hc` are always `char`. (Documented for VS2003 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and VC6 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272936%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) (Not sure about `%ws` and when it was really added))

Mapping `%s` to the natural width of the function was really handy back in the days of Win9x vs. WinNT, by using the [`tchar.h` header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx) you could build narrow and wide releases from the same source. When `_UNICODE` is defined the functions in `tchar.h` map to the wide functions and `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, otherwise the narrow functions are used and `TCHAR` is `char`:

```
_tprintf(_T("%c %s\n"), _T('a'), _T("Bcd"));
```

There is a similar convention used by the Windows SDK header files and the few format functions that exist there (wsprintf, wvsprintf, wnsprintf and wvnsprintf) but they are controlled by `UNICODE` and `TEXT` and not `_UNICODE` and `_T`/`_TEXT`.

You probably have 3 choices to make a multi-platform project work on Windows if you want to support older Windows compilers:

**1)** Compile as a narrow string project on Windows, probably not a good idea and in your case swprintf will still treat %s as wchar_t*.

**2)** Use custom defines similar to how inttypes.h format strings work:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define PRIs "s"
#define WPRIs L"hs"
#else
#define PRIs "s"
#define WPRIs L"s" 
#endif
printf("%" PRIs " World\n", "Hello");
wprintf(L"%" WPRIs L" World\n", "Hello");
```

**3)** Create your own custom version of swprintf and use it with Visual Studio 13 and earlier.

Comment: Im really not sure how to use this, in my tests when _UNICODE is defined or not defined the behaviour is the same swprintf %s expects a wchar_t and not a char*. As for the MS extensions do you know if there is a way to get gcc to use them?

Comment: Are you sure your environment is not defining it for you (In the project settings in VS)? If by gcc you mean MinGW then yes, MinGW can use the MS C run time, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729013/mingw-printf-size-specification-character-h

Comment: no gcc on mac... In the project settings you specific the character type as 'not defined' or 'use unicode' or 'use multibyte'. If you say 'not defined' then _UNICODE is not defined, if you say 'use unicode' then _UNICODE is defined.

Comment: You will probably only find support for %hs and %ls on the windows platform, to stay portable you can make up your own PRN define for strings like inttypes.h does for numbers if you want to avoid #ifdef's

Comment: ..I somehow missed the fact that you said swprintf, swprintf is the wide version no matter what the define is, sprintf is the narrow version and _stprintf (tchar.h) depends on the define. Assuming your destination is wchar_* the problem is unchanged and you will need MS specific format strings...

Comment: thanks for your help anders, and neil you've been good sounding boards.

Comment: The feature has been reverted, as said from your link above. You still don't need `_CRT_STDIO_LEGACY_WIDE_SPECIFIERS`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `%ls` format which always means `wchar_t*`.

Comment: its not an issue with wchar_t being seen as char* its an issue with char * being seen as wchar_t.  Plus I dont think %ls works on old visual studios... Thanks anyways neil.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find a compatible way to specify a `char*`, but I actually looked up %ls on the VS7.1 documentation, so that's quite a way back.

Comment: Yup I can confirm that %ls does work at least as far back as VS2008 which is what I'm on, thanks for that. I also found it in the documentation and apparently its what I should have been using instead of %S all along as I guess %S is very non standard thing. But really what could be more non standard than making %s equal to a wchar_t. The only thing I thought of is redirecting all my *wprint* to a wrapper function that I could write that would change the %s as necesary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "%Ts" format specifier or you can define _CRT_STDIO_LEGACY_WIDE_SPECIFIERS=1.

Read this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/18/crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx