# Behavior of `swprintf` when passed a `char const*` matching a `L"%s"` specifier

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++-2012

I'm writing an Excel plugin, and need to generate `wchar_t`
output for Excel (although internally, we are 100% `char`, and
in fact limit `char` to plain ASCII).  At one point, I'm using
`swprintf` to do the conversion:

```
static wchar_t buffer[ 32369 ];
buffer[0] = swprintf( buffer + 1, sizeof(buffer) - 1, L"#%s!", message );
```

Excel displays some sort of CJK characters, although `message`
(type `char const*`) is a null terminated character string with
no characters outside of printable ASCII (hex values 0x20-0x7E).

I've tried this in a small test program, dumping in hex the
generated string, and it looks like VC++ is treating `message`
as if it were a `wchar_t const*` (although it seems to
recognized the `'\0'` correctly, although it is on a single
byte); this results in `wchar_t` with values like `0x6568`
(rather than the `0x0068, 0x0065` that I was expecting).

According to the C99 standard, for a `"%s"` specifier,
`swprintf` should convert the characters from the `char const*`
"as if by repeated calls to the `mbrtowc` function[...]".  Is
the behavior I am seeing is an error in the Visual C++ library,
or whether there is something in the global locale that I have
to change?

(FWIW: when I compile and run my small test program with g++,
I get the behavior I expect.  G++ is not, however, an option for
our Excel plugins, at least not at present.)

Comment: Did you run `std::setlocale("")` at the beginning of your program?

Comment: @KerrekSB I can't.  I'm writing a plugin: I don't know what Excel has done, and I suspect that I can't modify the global locale in my plugin either.

Comment: Your length `sizeof(buffer)-1` is too small by a factor `sizeof(wchar_t)`. The length is a (wide) character count, not a size in bytes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that from [swprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf(v=vs.90).aspx) of MSDN:

> swprintf is a wide-character version of sprintf; the pointer arguments to swprintf are wide-character strings.

and then in the example:

```
wchar_t buf[100];
int len = swprintf( buf, 100, L"%s", L"Hello world" );
```

so at least Microsoft documented this.

And then in the page of [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w(v=vs.90).aspx)

> **s** String When used with printf functions, specifies a single-byte–character string; when used with wprintf functions, specifies a wide-character string. Characters are printed up to the first null character or until the precision value is reached.

And then

> **S** String When used with printf functions, specifies a wide-character string; when used with wprintf functions, specifies a single-byte–character string. Characters are printed up to the first null character or until the precision value is reached.

So what you want is upper-case `%S`.

See even this similar question: [visual studio swprintf is making all my %s formatters want wchar_t * instead of char *](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10000723/613130) where they suggest using `%ls` (always consider the parameter `wchar_t*`) and `%hs` (always consider the parameter `char*`)

Comment: OK.  Just another case of Microsoft inventing their own standards.  (They've been a lot better in this regard since they hired Herb.  I guess this is just one left over.)  In this case, however, it doesn't matter, since I'm pretty sure we'll never have to port the Excel plugin to Unix.  So I'll just conform with what Microsoft wants.

Comment: And this will teach me to use the C standard as documentation, rather than Microsoft's own pages:-).

Comment: @JamesKanze If you think one minute, it was a logical way to do it for Microsoft, because they loved the `_t*` functions that work both for Unicode and SBCS and are declared through the use of macros (like, in this case, `_stprintf`)

Comment: I'd not complain if `_stprintf` did something different; it's not standard, and it wouldn't even occur to me to use it.  (On the other hand, the fact that function names like `LoadLibrary` are actually macros is a real pain.)  But `swprintf` has a behavior specified by the C standard.  Their modifications mean that it can't easily be used in portable code.  (Of course, in this case, I'm only using it because I have to conform to the Excel C ABI, so portability isn't an issue.)

Comment: What's worse is that the documentation explicitly claims "swprintf conforms to the ISO C Standard". From the context it is clear that they do not mean that at all, but they do claim it nonetheless.

Comment: This might be due to the infamous `wsprintf`(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which dates back to Windows 2.0 IIRC. Released in 1987, it predates ANSI C by 2 years.

Comment: visual studio 2015 is different. "%s" is for char* regardless of _UNICODE/UNICODE.

Answer (score 2):

When calling `swprintf` the specifier **%s** is interpreted as pointing to a wide string, i.e. a wchar_t pointer. Instead use the **%S** (uppercase S) format specifier, as that will correctly use the `char* message` you are passing.

From Microsoft's documentation on printf Type Field Characters:

- **s**, String,  When used with **printf** functions, specifies a single-byte–character string; when used with **wprintf** functions, specifies a wide-character string. Characters are printed up to the first null character or until the precision value is reached.
- **S**, String, When used with **printf** functions, specifies a wide-character string; when used with **wprintf** functions, specifies a single-byte–character string. Characters are printed up to the first null character or until the precision value is reached.